# Is it possible to generate a push notification or something that alerts me when I'm close to a place?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an application in which I have saved several places and on a map using the native google maps plugin. I would like to know if there is something that will notify me when I am near one of those registered places?
my question is to know if it is possible to do it or what alternatives can I do.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need background processing + Geolocation

Try these plugins:

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/wiki/Geofence-Features

https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence